# Passing click handler to angular component "the right way"

Tags: javascript, angular

Let's say we have an angular component that is pretty much a styled button that we're going to use throughout the app. What is the right way to pass a click handler to that component? Because as far as I know there are two ways to do it.

1.
We simply pass it to the component's selector like so

```
<app-styled-button (click)="handleClick()"></app-styled-button>
```

2.
We use the

```
@Input() onClick
```

then

```
<app-styled-button onClick="handleClick()"></app-styled-button>
```

and then in the styled button template

```
<button (click)="onClick()">
...
</button>
```

I've done some basic testing and it seems to be working fine with both approaches, but are there any benefits from using one over the other? I mean the first option uses much less code but the second somehow *feels* like the right way to do it. I am however new to angular so I'm still calibrating my moral compass :D

Comment: It's a bit confusing. Are you trying to pass click event from the button which is inside `app-styled-button` component to your parent component? Or are you trying to pass a click event to your `app-styled-button` component from the parent component? Option A require `@Output` instead of `@Input` as explained in my aswere.

Comment: The `app-styled-button` is supposed to be a reusable button that will do different things in different places in app while looking more or less the same. In one place it may add a new user and in the other it may add a new comment. What I'm trying to figure out is what's the best way to pass those functions so they are executed when this styled button is clicked.

Comment: Ok so in this case, you want to pass the click event from the button to the parent (host) component. Please have a look at my answere.

Answer (score 2):

In your first case, you are listening to the click event rised on your component instead of you button. This is not the same event, the event parameters will not be the same.

I suggest you to pass the button click event through you component.
In this case, you have to use `@Output` instead of `@Input` to pass the event. Please take a look at the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

I've created a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tps7zk

Comment: You were right! However, it would be really cool show the way can be created and used in code. [Provide context for links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thank you! I added a Stackblitz example.